# Angular JS $HTTP for nested array

Tags: javascript, angular.js, api

I'm using a factory for my $http get requests.

When I pull single json objects from the $http, it works pretty quickly

I now have items coming through as an array. It is very inefficient, & slow. Images 'pop' in.

Ideally it would just load one list (of say 10 images) then know to load the next list, say after 4 swipes.

I can configure the API to output as many results as are efficient. NB it takes around 2.8seconds to load the result.

I'd also like to create custom directive to only display a maximum of two items (ie 1 in front, 1 behind).

**In a plunker**
http://plnkr.co/edit/R4L89zii3txxtkWOZkOn?p=preview

The raw code:

```
.factory('cardsApi', ['$http', function($http) {
  var apiUrl = 'http://***.com/api/list/';

  var getApiData = function() {
    return $http.get(apiUrl)
  };

  return {
    getApiData: getApiData
  };
 }])

.controller('CardsCtrl', ['$scope', 'TDCardDelegate', 'cardsApi', '$http',
    function($scope, TDCardDelegate, cardsApi, $http) {
       console.log('CARDS CTRL');

        // <======  Rewrite with accounts preferences
             for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                 cardsApi.getApiData()
                     .then(function (result) {
                         //console.log(result.data) //Shows log of API incoming
                         $scope.product_id = result.data.product_id;
                         $scope.cards= result.data;
                     })
                     .catch(function (err) {
                         $log.error(err);
                     });
             }

             $scope.$watchCollection('cards', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                 if(newVal < oldVal) {
                     cardsApi.getApiData()
                         .then(function (result) {

                             // console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data)); Shows log of API results

                             $scope.cards = result.data;

                             // console.log($scope.cards);

                         })
                         .catch(function (err) {
                             console.log(err);
                         });
                 }
             });

             $scope.cardSwiped = function(card) {
         console.log('here');
         console.log(card);
       };

       //$scope.cards = Array.prototype.slice.call(cardTypes, 0);

         //Removes card from top of stack
         $scope.cardDestroyed = function(index) {
             $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
         };

         $scope.addCard = function() {
             var newCard = $scope.cards[$scope.cards.length];
             //newCard.id = Math.random();
             $scope.cards.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
         };

        $scope.postRecordLikes = function(product_id){
            console.log(product_id)
            $http.post('http://test.com/analytic/' + product_id)
                .then(function successCallback(product_id) {
                    // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                });
        };
    }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

For one, you throw a lot of logging functions inside your code. For debugging, I'd suggest using the browser debugger an plant breakpoints on interesting lines. When using breakpoints, you see more than just the variable. You see what's in scope, all the values of the variables visible etc.

If you *do* use the logging, I also suggest making them consistent. Since you're on Angular, use the `$log`. Additionally, it's better if you move your logging to the service layer rather than in the controller layer. That way, it's the API's duty, not the controller.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  cardsApi.getApiData()
```

Not sure what the loop is for when you're just calling it once. You're not using the `i` either. Remove the loop.

```
$scope.postRecordLikes = function(product_id){
  console.log(product_id)
  $http.post('http://test.com/analytic/' + product_id)
```

You had a service layer to handle the API call earlier, yet have an API call down here in the controller. Suggesting you move out this API call into a service, a function that accepts a product ID. That way, it's defined once, reusable everywhere.

Also suggesting you move out your configs to constants/values. That way, they're easily modifiable later on by just changing the value/constant rather than digging through code. Candidates for these are your API endpoint urls.

Now from the looks of it, the code is small and I don't see problems with it in terms of performance. However, I do see that you're using a remote location for your API calls. You should check your network latency, another task that requires the browser debugger. Also, if possible, just test locally during development.